# Xcode attempted to install a beta profile without the proper entitlement

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

Xcode 15.0.1 15A507 with iPhone 14 Pro MQ0E3LL/A on iOS 17.0.3 attached via USB Lightning trying to build and install iOS app on phone that had previously had no issues building.

Building app to iPhone from Xcode gives error: "xcode failed to installed embedded profile.
Attempted to install a beta profile without the proper entitlement."

Same with my iPad Pro over USB C, same error.

Have tried cleaning build folder, deleting derived data, deleting provisioning profiles and downloading again. Tried removing iPhone from Devices and Simulators and adding back, trusting again. Recreated a new provisioning profile and removed old, installed new, and same error. Certificates, Profiles and Agreements are all up to date and not expired.

```
Full Xcode error is:
Unable to Install “APPNAME”
Domain: IXUserPresentableErrorDomain
Code: 14
Failure Reason: This app cannot be installed because its integrity could not be verified.
Recovery Suggestion: Failed to install embedded profile for BUNDLE ID : 0xe800801f 
(Attempted to install a Beta profile without the proper entitlement.) 
Verify that the Developer App certificate for your account is trusted on your device. 
Open Settings on the device and navigate to General -> VPN & Device Management, then select 
your Developer App certificate to trust it.
User Info: {
DVTErrorCreationDateKey = "2023-10-25 12:37:01 +0000";
IDERunOperationFailingWorker = IDEInstallCoreDeviceWorker;
Domain: MIInstallerErrorDomain
Code: 13
User Info: {
FunctionName = "-[MIInstallableBundle _installEmbeddedProfilesWithError:]";
LegacyErrorString = ApplicationVerificationFailed;
LibMISErrorNumber = "-402620385";
SourceFileLine = 200;
```

In Xcode, going to Devices and Simulators and selecting Show Provisioning Profiles on any connected devices doesn't show any in the list. With "no provisioning profiles installed." Choosing the + and trying to add my downloaded profile gives error "failed to install one or more provisioning profiles on this device. Ensure the provisioning profile is configured for this device." Although, i never had to go in here and manually add profiles before.

On any device, going to Settings and navigating to General -> VPN & Device Management shows nothing.as the error suggests to select your Developer App certificate to trust it. Never had to that before either.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My solution was to go to developer.apple.com / Devices and add my devices using Device ID (UDID). This was obtained by plugging device into a mac, selecting in finder, and clicking the top device banner to copy the UDID. I then had to create a new ad hoc profile and add the devices to the profile. Finally, I had to download and select the new profile in Targets / Signing and Capabilities.

This is strange because I never had to do this before when I was using my regular "app store" profile. So, I am not 100% sure this is the answer. Shouldn't a provisioning profile of "app store" type be able to run on connected devices without a specific separate ad hoc profile?

Comment: I am encountering this for the first time today too, on Version 15.0 (15A240d), iPhone Pro 13 Max and iOS 17.0.3...

Comment: Confirmed still happening on iOS 17.1

Comment: The UDID can be found via Xcode Devices and Simulators window.